# Setting the minimum and maximum date for a UIDatepicker which is put inside a Action sheet

Tags: ios, uidatepicker, uiactionsheet

I am using this class for displaying the date picker called  [Action sheet picker](https://github.com/TimCinel/ActionSheetPicker),
The problem which I am having is that I am not able to set the max and min date of the picker.

The code which i am using is this:

In tableview didSelectRow method:

```
  else if (indexPath.row == 2){
        // here I am using a library which successfully shows a date picker from where we can pick the dates on which we want to request the appt.
        _actionSheetPicker = [[ActionSheetDatePicker alloc] initWithTitle:@"" 
      datePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime selectedDate:self.selectedDateandTime 
   target:self action:@selector(dateWasSelected:element:) origin:[self.tableView
  cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
        [self.actionSheetPicker addCustomButtonWithTitle:[self.selectedDateandTime 
      getDateStringInFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"] value:Nil];
        UIDatePicker * picker = (UIDatePicker *)[self.actionSheetPicker 
     configuredPickerView];
        [picker setMinimumDate:self.selectedDateandTime];

        self.actionSheetPicker.hideCancel = NO;
        [self.actionSheetPicker showActionSheetPicker];
}
```

the configuredPickerView method is in the library which is as follows:

```
- (UIView *)configuredPickerView {
CGRect datePickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, self.viewSize.width, 216);
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:datePickerFrame];
datePicker.datePickerMode = self.datePickerMode;
[datePicker setDate:self.selectedDate animated:NO];


[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(eventForDatePicker:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

//need to keep a reference to the picker so we can clear the DataSource / Delegate when dismissing (not used in this picker, but just in case somebody uses this as a template for another picker)
self.pickerView = datePicker;

return datePicker;
```

}

Please if somebody can help me out on this matter. if any extra help is required to understand the architecture of the class then please feel free to ask me.

Comment: why you are not making simple method to set max and min date to picker?

Comment: can u suggest me how to do that and how it will be compatible with actionsheetpicker library

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem , so i wrote a method in [ActionSheetPicker-3.0](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0)

Add This in your `ActionSheetPicker-3.0` Library.

```
// ActionSheetDatePicker.h
+ (id)showPickerWithTitle:(NSString *)title datePickerMode:(UIDatePickerMode)datePickerMode selectedDate:(NSDate *)selectedDate minimumDate:(NSDate *)minimumDate maximumDate:(NSDate *)maximumDate target:(id)target action:(SEL)action origin:(id)origin;


// ActionSheetDatePicker.m
+ (id)showPickerWithTitle:(NSString *)title datePickerMode:(UIDatePickerMode)datePickerMode selectedDate:(NSDate *)selectedDate minimumDate:(NSDate *)minimumDate maximumDate:(NSDate *)maximumDate target:(id)target action:(SEL)action origin:(id)origin;
{
    ActionSheetDatePicker *picker = [[ActionSheetDatePicker alloc] initWithTitle:title datePickerMode:datePickerMode selectedDate:selectedDate target:target action:action origin:origin];
    picker.minimumDate = minimumDate;
    picker.maximumDate = maximumDate;
    [picker showActionSheetPicker];
    return picker;
}
```

write this code where you want to use ActionSheetDatePicker

```
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *maximumDateComponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [maximumDateComponents setYear:2050];
    NSDate *minDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *maxDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:maximumDateComponents];


[ActionSheetDatePicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Select Start Date" datePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate selectedDate:[NSDate date] minimumDate:minDate maximumDate:maxDate target:self action:@selector(dateSelected:element:) origin:sender];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIDatePicker properties:-

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *minimumDate; // 
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *maximumDate; // default is nil
```